# Get Customized Child Values into Grid using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

I have the following three  Tables...

**PatientEligibilities**

**PatientEligibilitiesServiceItems**

**ServiceItems**

The Relation Between Tables as following:

One to Many between : **PatientEligibilities** and **PatientEligibilitiesServiceItems**

One to One  between : **PatientEligibilitiesServiceItems** and  **ServiceItems**

I retrieved **PatientEligibilitiesObject**

I need to fill  grid with **PatientEligibilitiesServiceItems**

i did the following:

```
dt = CreateDT("Code", "Description")
 If PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesServiceItems.Count > 0 Then
         For Each LST In PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesServiceItems  
           Dim res = HMSData.ServiceItems.Single(Function(ds) ds.ID = LST.ServiceItemID)
           dt.Rows.Add(res.Code, res.EngName)
         Next
 Else
        dt.Rows.Add("", "")
 End If
       uwg.DataSource = dt
```

This solution is working fine.. but i believe it's not the Best Or even Good one..

i tried the following:

```
uwg.DataSource = PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties.GetNewBindingList()
```

It gave me all columns in the Table .. like **ServiceItemID** and also **ServiceItem**

But i need to get **ServiceItem.Code** and **ServiceItem.EngName**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep the this solution since using direct binding from LINQ query to grid will be more complex.